# What is the Magic Damage Die (MDD)?

Tags: spells, dead-winter-rpg

I noticed that every spellcaster class have an entry called Magic Damage Die, or MDD. Sorcerers have a stated MDD of "d10", wizards a "d6", and so on.

How exactly those numbers affect something in the game?

Comment: Hey, @Thales... do you have a link to the game you're talking about? While we don't discourage self-answered questions, a pattern of them to a game few have heard about begs a few questions. Remember, our rules on self-promotion [*require* disclosure of the relationship.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't resist asking: What is this Dead Winter RPG that you keep asking *and answering* questions about? Is this perhaps your own creation? Are you kind of promoting it through these self-answered questions? If so, a disclosure would be quite welcome, I think. :)

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I'm not self-promoting, at all. I created a meta about this to clear possible misunderstanding: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/about-dead-winter-questions

Comment: @OpaCitiZen My creation? Yes. Promoting? Not my intention, at all. Im here to put those questions, and their answers, so people that use the DWRPG could find them easily. I created a meta on this, look at me other comment.

Comment: @ThalesSarczuk Excellent. Thanks. I've upvoted your meta Q (and practically all the answers. :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Magic Damage Die, or MDD, is *what you actually rolls* when casting a spell that does some form of damage.

Spells on DWRPG have a really distinct feature: they don't have a fixed die of damage, as it was on Pathfinder and D&D. When you look at a spell description, you will see something like this:

> ***Fireball***
>   [...]
>   *Area:* a 6 meters burst from the point of detonation.
>   *Damage:* **1d** per caster level of fire damage.

Notice the "1d per caster level". That means that a Fireball spell, cast by a 10th level wizard, would deal 10 dice worth of fire damage.

But **which** dice?

That's where the MDD comes in. Each class have a certain die as its MDD. Wizards have a d6 for its MDD, so when the wizard from the example casts a Fireball, it would deal 10d6 worth of fire damage.

Some classes have different MDD's. Sorcerer, for example, have the biggest "natural" MDD of the game, d10,  feats and builds aside. That means that, when a 10th level sorcerer casts the same Fireball, it would deal a whooping 10d10 of fire damage, almost the double of what our wizard could put up.

This is meant as a balancing mechanic. Wizards have a gigantic repertorie. Sorcerers have an awesome damage output. Clerics and Druids fall somewhere between, having a good, meaty d8 as their damage die - but having far less impressive, flashy spells. Each class will have a MDD that balances the other features of that class - spontaneous vs prepared spellcasting, daily limit, spell list, etc.

Some feats and specific builds can raise the MDD for a given spell. So, let's say that our sorcerer is a 10th level sorcerer from the Fire Elemental Bloodline. He will have this Bloodline power avaliable to him:

> **Unforgiving Fire:** Once per day per point of it's Charisma modifier, the Sorcerer can raise his MDD one step up for a single round for all of his fire spells. Any spells cast during that round which have the Fire descriptor will use the altered MDD. Activating this bloodline power is a swift action.

If there's not any other effect that changes his MDD, this sorcerer would be casting a massive Fireball capable of doing 10d12 of damage! That's a TON of damage, and where the Sorcerer show his shine most.

A *Magic Dampening* spell, on the other hand, lowers the target MDD one step down for a while. So, a regular Sorcerer hit by this spell would deal damage using d8's, instead of d10's (before considering other effects).

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this system.